# Why is SweetAlert not appearing in the correct format?

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js, sweetalert

Below is my code for one of my AJAX calls. When it goes in to the `else` condition the SweetAlert code does not trigger with that code format. I don't know why. When I use this code instead it works fine:

```
swal("Task is still in progress", "Wait for status change to Done", "warning");
```

Since I want to redirect to a page on clicking OK on swal I can't use this code.
What could be the reason why?

```js
if (placeholder4Status == 'Done') {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/addTasks-approve",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      text: text,
      id: id
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.status == '200') {
        window.location.replace('/tasksAdmin');
        $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
      }
    }
  });
} else {
  $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
  // swal("Task is still in progress", "Wait for status change to Done ", "warning");
  swal({
    title: "Task is still in progress!",
    text: "Please wait for status change to Done ",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true
  }, function() {
    window.location.href = '/tasksAdmin';
    // window.location.replace('/tasksAdmin');
  });

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not quite right in placing the function that executes `window.location.href`. Instead, you can try changing your code using [Promises](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises), here's an example:

```
swal({
  title: "Task is still in progress!",
  text: "Please wait for status change to Done ",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true
}).then((result) => {
  if (result) {
     window.location.href = '/tasksAdmin';
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now its working but the icon illustration is not appearing in swal mean for error, warning and success. Only the text is popuping up.

Comment: You can try changing from `type: "..."` to `icon: "..."`. You can see how it is used  [here](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-options).